# Stretch region of image through opencv or opengl in iOS

Tags: ios, image, opencv, image-processing, opengl-es

I am trying to make double chin in fat image as mentioned in my desired result image below.

[image]

I have morphed the normal face to fat face by wrapping an image on mesh and deformed the mesh.

1. Original image

[image]

2. Wrapped image on mesh grid with vertex points displaced
   [image]
3. Current result image

[image]

I tried a lot by arranging mesh points but could not get the result like I have shown in first image.

Any ideas how to achieve this by open GL or open CV in iOS?

Comment: can you show your morphed code?

Comment: Hi Anjumbhai, i need your help for how to store ArrayLit<BluetoothGattService> object to db. where BluetoothGattSerivce is non-serializable object. i try to convert to serializable. bt not possible. any another way to store this objects.

Comment: Did you get any success here?

Comment: @Anjum Shrimali have you got solution for this prob?

Comment: @Anjum Shrimali - I am looking the source code for stretch region of image. Please help me. Thanks,

Comment: I am sorry for being too late on this question. But its was possible. I had created a mesh grid keeping lips as center and stretched it slightly outwards. Then added a transparent overly over chin for that area look like chin. Hope this might help.

Comment: how to waring image concept i don't know so please any one do u know how to possible  this concept let me know please

Comment: @AnjumShrimali, Do we've any other option along with opencv to achieve "Stretch region of image through opencv or opengl in iOS" ? Also can you provide any reference of opencv to detect face and perform face retouch on it?

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious from the first image that there is an added effect to produce the double or triple chin.
This actually looks like a either a preset image blended into the original or a scale and stretched version of the original chin blended into the warped image.